# Google Sheets formula to convert my 5 cell lat 5 cell long to whatever google needs for maps

Tags: gps

I gathered 82 site coords during a soil test and wanted to map them, i entered them in individual cells, for example lat "38,49,41,638,N" is in 5 cells and "78,26,59,256,w" is in 5 more cells, what is the formula for converting these into whatever google sheets needs so i can use these with google maps in the reporting in google data studio, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figure it out
=G2+(H1/60)+(I2+(J2/1000))/3600 & ",-" & uminus(L2+(M1/60)+(N2+(O2/1000))/3600)
returns
38.0106247222222,-78.01646

left to right is 4 cells for lat and 4 cells for long

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).